# Vue 3.0: Pass given object to View

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Hi i'm struggling sending an object to a view via the router here is my setup:

router.js:

```
...{
path: '/player/:id',
name: 'Player',
component: Player,
props: true
```

}

Link:

```
<router-link :to="{name:'Player', params:{id:video.snippet.resourceId.videoId}, query:{video:video}}" class="uk-position-cover"></router-link>
```

The Videolink can be sent and is accessible but i need the additional video data too.

All i get in the Player.vue is [[Object Object]] - so how can i pass a whole object and not just strings?

My Player.vue script:

```
export default {props: ['id','video'],components : {  },data(){console.log(this.$route)return{}}}
```

i tried already to pass the video object via params, props, query...

Edit:
When i do this in VideoLink.vue (file that contains the router link to Player.vue) i can see the Video Object in the console:
[image: VideoLink.vue Script]

[image: Browserconsole]

any hints regarding this?

Comment: try printing console.log(this.$route) in mounted inside Player.vue

Comment: it results also in : query:
video: "[object Object]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should serialize your object as JSON (and deserialize in your view) - URLs are strings and therefore can not contain objects so objects must be serialized to strings. `router-link` does not automatically serialize for you - it just calls the `toString()` method of the object which simply returns `[object Object]`.